# Rebasing commit from one parent onto another

Tags: git, rebase, git-rewrite-history

I have an existing repository that I'm working on, yet recently I've learned a lot about good practices and the git itself. I wanted to shake my history to my liking, especially some early commits.

Below is the fragment of the current history. I want to rebase the e5cb9b8 commit onto the 1a92e84 so I can have just one/two levels of depth in the history graph (visually, changing the parent of e5cb9b8). I've tried rebasing

```
git rebase -p --onto 1a92e84 e5cb9b8 master
```

and cherrypicking into new branch created from 9ecbe00. Cherrypicking gets me flat history, rebase fails with the following message

> error: commit ca230d8c048d22de6f219da8a22e70a773827c38 is a merge but no -m option was given.
>
> fatal: cherry-pick failed
>
> Could not pick ca230d8c048d22de6f219da8a22e70a773827c38

```
* | 45a0a21 - (7 weeks ago) #17 Updates README.md - Kamil Pacanek
|/
*   ca230d8 - (8 weeks ago) Merge pull request #2 from KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts - Kamil Pacanek
|\
| * e5cb9b8 - (8 weeks ago) Adds support for removing parts on ReactorCells - KamilPacanek
* |   1a92e84 - (8 weeks ago) Merge pull request #1 from KamilPacanek/enable-gh-pages - Kamil Pacanek
|\ \
| |/
| * 81761ff - (8 weeks ago) Adds GH Pages support - KamilPacanek
|/
* 9ecbe00 - (8 weeks ago) Initial commit - KamilPacanek
```

Expected:

```
* | 45a0a21' - (7 weeks ago) #17 Updates README.md - Kamil Pacanek
|/
*   ca230d8' - (8 weeks ago) Merge pull request #2 from KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts - Kamil Pacanek
|\
| * e5cb9b8' - (8 weeks ago) Adds support for removing parts on ReactorCells - KamilPacanek
|/
*    1a92e84 - (8 weeks ago) Merge pull request #1 from KamilPacanek/enable-gh-pages - Kamil Pacanek
|\ 
| |
| * 81761ff - (8 weeks ago) Adds GH Pages support - KamilPacanek
|/
* 9ecbe00 - (8 weeks ago) Initial commit - KamilPacanek
```

I've searched the StackOverflow for similar issues and it seems like no one described such modifications so deep into the history.

### Solution

Ok, for future readers and myself I'm writing down the solution for my problem. @alfunx [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363781/6710729) was a key to solve it - I've tracked down in other topic explanation of `git rebase` and `git rebase --onto` and started to experiment on my repository. Through trial and error, I've managed* to achieve the expected history graph by executing

```
git rebase -ir --onto 1a92e84 81761ff develop
```

and replacing followig fragment of todo-list

```
label onto

# Branch KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts
reset onto
pick e5cb9b8 Adds support for removing parts on ReactorCells
label KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts

# Branch enh/add-uranium-cells
reset 9ecbe00 # Initial commit
merge -C 1a92e84 onto # Merge pull request #1 from KamilPacanek/enable-gh-pages
merge -C ca230d8 KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts # Merge pull request #2 from KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts
label branch-point
```

with following (changed the reset position and removed one, redundant, merge commit):

```
label onto

# Branch KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts
reset onto
pick e5cb9b8 Adds support for removing parts on ReactorCells
label KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts

# Branch enh/add-uranium-cells
reset onto
merge -C ca230d8 KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts # Merge pull request #2 from KamilPacanek/feat/rmb-support-removing-parts
label branch-point
```

*)
Actually, there was more to do to achieve that state, but I don't want to obfuscate the solution with secondary issues. First `git rebase` failed with that message:

> error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'refs/rewritten/Implement-durability-loss.'
>
> hint: Could not execute the todo command
>
> hint:     label Implement-durability-loss.

As you can see I have a period at the end of the commit message. After I solved that (with another rebase with `reword` command) I was able to move forward.

Also, it seems like `git rebase --abort` [doesn't clear](http://ou63pmih66umazou.darknet.to/git/xmqqpnoujlj4.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/t/) the refs that are created during `git rebase -r`.. so I had a mess in history. Solved that one via `rm -rf .git/refs/rewritten`. Another thing, I had a leftover .git/sequencer folder that was removable via `git revert --quit`.

Comment: How useful is a history which is *not* the history of what happened, but rather a cured retelling of how events *should* have been? I totally get that you want to enforce better practices now, but is this history rewriting needed for something else than theoretical cleanliness?

Comment: @RomainValeri for practice mostly. Right now when you asked that question I consider leaving the history as it is, after I find a solution for this topic. Thank you for reminding me of what git history is about.

Comment: Don't get me wrong : I don't view your question as futile or useless, I'm very much in the learning process myself, and often wonder about questions similar to yours, with probably the same amount of theoretical concern :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The base you chose for the rebase is wrong and should be `81761ff` instead of `e5cb9b8`. I would suggest you to do an interactive rebase and use `--rebase-merges` instead of `--preserve-merges`. So the command should be:

```
git rebase -ir --onto 1a92e84 81761ff master
```

Now, Git will probably produce one additional merge commit. To avoid that and to produce your desired outcome, you should adjust the todo-list to something like:

```
label onto
pick e5cb9b8 Adds support for removing parts on ReactorCells
label new
reset onto
merge -C ca230d8 new
pick 45a0a21 #17 Updates README.md
# Remaining commits...
```

In the todo-list, `label` can be used to mark the current commit (`HEAD`), and `reset` can be used to set the `HEAD` to some commit/label. `merge` is obviously used to produce a merge commit, `-C` makes the merge use the same commit message as the original merge commit.

This is quite advanced and *really* not needed for most users and use cases, so please consider `man git-rebase`, section *Rebase Merges* (or [the online version here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges)) for more in depth information. The example there is actually quite similar to your situation.

Comment: Thank you @alfunx! That was very helpful as I was able to achieve what I wanted. I've updated the question with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you go with `git rebase -ir`, do so with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

A label used in the `todo` list that are generated by "`git rebase --rebase-merges`" is used as a part of a refname; the logic to come up with the label has been tightened to avoid names that cannot be used as such.

See [commit cd55222](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd5522271f6b985114b33332e148bff2283b0440) (17 Nov 2019) by [Matthew Rogers (`soniqua`)](https://github.com/soniqua).
See [commit 867bc1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/867bc1d236b8955414b3dbacf28c7f0c2e337cf4) (17 Nov 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 917d0d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/917d0d6234be4c6ce4ab0feea15911bfa5e65253), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -r`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd5522271f6b985114b33332e148bff2283b0440): let `label` generate safer labels
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthew Rogers</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> The `label` todo command in interactive rebases creates temporary refs in the `refs/rewritten/` namespace. These refs are stored as loose refs, i.e. as files in `.git/refs/rewritten/`, therefore they have to conform with file name limitations on the current filesystem in addition to the accepted ref format.
>
> This poses a problem in particular on NTFS/FAT, where e.g. the colon, double-quote and pipe characters are disallowed as part of a file name.
>
> Let's safeguard against this by replacing not only white-space characters by dashes, but all non-alpha-numeric ones.
>
> However, we exempt non-ASCII UTF-8 characters from that, as it should be quite possible to reflect branch names such as `↯↯↯` in refs/file names.

---

And:

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), The logic to avoid duplicate label names generated by "`git rebase --rebase-merges`" forgot that the machinery itself uses "`onto`" as a label name, which must be avoided by auto-generated labels, which has been corrected.

See [commit e02058a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e02058a72967b18bd906674de6191f42d03b0763) (18 Nov 2019) by [Doan Tran Cong Danh (`congdanhqx-zz`)](https://github.com/congdanhqx-zz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 995b1b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/995b1b1411e5ad45d100354f4a6c185fef79cbf6), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e02058a72967b18bd906674de6191f42d03b0763): handle rebase-merges for "onto" message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Doan Tran Cong Danh</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> In order to work correctly, [`git rebase --rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins) needs to make initial todo list with unique labels.
>
> Those unique labels is being handled by employing a hashmap and appending an unique number if any duplicate is found.
>
> But, we forget that beside those labels for side branches, we also have a special label `onto` for our so-called new-base.
>
> In a special case that any of those labels for side branches named `onto', git will run into trouble.
>
> Correct it.

---

Another possible issue: Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) corrects an error where [`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3b041ea5f7a3700a82cae479dc7f6d37e59569d2/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> would mistakenly use a branch or tag named "`refs/rewritten/xyz`" when missing a rebase label.

See [commit 688d82f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/688d82f254f8fc5da019fc4962e6e8646767aba0), [commit 82766b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82766b29611aea7c3fb42a99debfba1436852d38) (10 Nov 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b041ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b041ea5f7a3700a82cae479dc7f6d37e59569d2), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/688d82f254f8fc5da019fc4962e6e8646767aba0): tighten label lookups
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The `label` command creates a ref `refs/rewritten/<label>` that the `reset` and `merge` commands resolve by calling `lookup_label()`.
> That uses `lookup_commit_reference_by_name()` to look up the label ref.
> As `lookup_commit_reference_by_name()` uses the dwim rules when looking up the label it will look for a branch named `refs/heads/refs/rewritten/<label>` and return that instead of an error if the branch exists and the label does not.
> Fix this by using `read_ref()` followed by `lookup_commit_object()` when looking up labels.

Note: [DWIM is short for Do What I Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM), where a system attempts to anticipate what users intend to do, correcting trivial errors automatically rather than blindly executing users' explicit but potentially incorrect inputs.