# What is the "todo command" in git?

Tags: git

When rebasing a commit that enables LFS in a repo I get this error message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        tests/example.bin
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     pick 8cfd395d3653812e33852e6aceeb2d7858770abe Set up LFS
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
Could not apply 8cfd395... Set up LFS
```

What is "the todo command"? It is just a really badly worded way of saying "the following command", i.e. the `pick`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would cause an interactive git rebase to fail without modifying the todo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892817/what-would-cause-an-interactive-git-rebase-to-fail-without-modifying-the-todo) - it may not, but it might help?

Comment: In addition to the provided answers, you might want to have a look at the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: this [Rebasing commit from one parent onto another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361900/rebasing-commit-from-one-parent-onto-another) maybe helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, although I think some people (other than just me that is) would take issue with your phrasing.  It's called a "todo command" because it is a command in the "todo file", which is the list of operations that the interactive rebase is supposed to do and has not yet done.  (I'd call it at most *somewhat* badly worded. )

Comment: `Could not execute the following command` would have been much clearer.

Comment: @Timmmm: That would immediately lead to complaints about `git rebase --edit-todo`, "what do you mean *todo* here, these are following commands!" :-)

Comment: Ha yes well I mean 90% of git is badly named. Of course it's mostly too late (though they did add `git switch`) I was just musing about what it *should have* been.