# Could not execute the todo command in simple case

Tags: git, rebase

During an interactive rebase, I wanted to move one commit to a different place in the history.

I ran this command:

> git rebase -i feature/NNN~10 feature/NNN

Inside the TODO editor, I made these changes:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| ... | ... |

Despite getting no merge conflicts, it failed with the following message:

```
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint:
hint:     pick 94ce720b8f977f72fba066175c819d9aec1041ba commit number 5
hint:
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint:
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
```

Since I couldn't see any action that I needed to take or any particular issue to resolve, I simply did `git rebase --continue`, which resulted in more errors happening so that I had to abort.

There are no merges to deal with. And, no merge conflicts from applying the first 3 TODOs (the change I wanted to make). Just a series of ~10 commits that I wanted to re-order, and an obscure message somewhere in the middle.

I was able to resolve this issue with git rebase, documented that as an answer below. There are similar questions related to this mysterious git error message, but are often in more complicated cases. I thought the simplicity of the scenario would help others better understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58892817/712526

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361900/rebasing-commit-from-one-parent-onto-another

Answer (score -1):

By rebasing against an earlier point in history, everything worked fine.

> git rebase -i feature/NNN~11 feature/NNN

Then, I made the same effective change in the TODO editor, but leaving the 0th commit alone:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: This is interesting, and I'd like to understand *why* this works. I wonder if showing `git log --graph feature/NNN` before and after the rebase would provide a clue.

Comment: I'll check it out; but with no merge commits, it's really pretty simple. I keep having this issue on this branch, though, so who knows?

Comment: If the top 12 commits *before* the rebase are linear, then I agree that showing the graph probably won't help much. Would it be possible to share an MRE?